# How can I go to homepage from another page in Django? I am unable to exit from last called definition

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

```
def save(request,id):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('name'):
            table=Userdb.objects.get(id=id)
            table.name=request.POST.get('name')
            table.url=request.POST.get('url')
            table.phone=request.POST.get('phone')
            table.dob=request.POST.get('dob')
            table.save()
            #messages.success(request,"record saved successfully")
        #return redirect('userlist')
    #return HttpResponseRedirect({%urls 'index'% })
    return render(request,"index.html")
```

Here at last part,I have directed to index.html. But actually I am not exited the save definition. please refer next snapshot.
The url in webpage dont show index.html but shows save. Also css of index webpage is lost.

I tried various urls but didnt work. Also tried to change setings.py still no avail.
I want to navigate to home page without trace of any older definition

Comment: show urls.py file

Comment: @Ivan Starostin u can directly use url  like `return redirect("https://example.com/")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use redirect to go to home page.
For URL I suggest to use reverse_lazy

import following:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```

redirection code:

```
return redirect(reverse_lazy("home"))
```

Please note, for reverse_lazy to work, the name of url should be "home" in urls.py

Comment: is used reverse instead of reverse_lazy and used HttpResponseRedirrect instead of redirect, it worked. Thanks for your contribution